# How to fix redux-observable Parameter 'action$' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-observable

I am trying to implement TS epic function, but "action$" need to have some implicit type that differs for , i could not find working example of this type of function...

I made function that works just fine but i cant fix TS error of ANY type.

```
export const fetchSettingsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(types.UPDATE_INITIAL_SETTINGS),
  mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON(url).pipe(
      map((response: Settings) => 
actions.updateInitialSuccess(response)),
      catchError(error => of(actions.updateInitialError(error))),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The function is pretty simple, but how can I fix "Parameter 'action$' implicitly has an 'any' type." error?

IMPORTANT! Dot tell me to turn off "noImplicitAny": true, or don't check this part of code )

Comment: Are you using `typesafe-actions` ?

Comment: I tried, but could not make it work without other type errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't turn off `noImplicityAny`. You are right, you shouldn't!

What you should do is, declare the type of the parameters, which is `ActionsObservable<T>`. Where T should be the type of the action.

Example:

```
export enum SettingsActionTypes {
   FETCH: "settings/fetch",
   FETCH_SUCCESS: "settings/fetchSuccess"
}

export function fetch(): IFetchAction {
   return {
       type: SettingsActionTypes.FETCH
   };
}

export interface IFetchAction {
   type: SettingsActionTypes.FETCH;
}

export interface IFetchSuccessAction {
   type: SettingsActionTypes.FETCH_SUCCESS;
}

export type SettingsAction = IFetchAction | IFetchSuccessAction;
```

Then in your epics, you can write something like this:

```
import {
   ActionsObservable,
   StateObservable
} from 'redux-observable';

export const fetchSettingsEpic = (action$: ActionsObservable<SettingsAction>) =>
      action$.ofType(SettingsActionTypes.FETCH).mergeMap(...do your stuff here...)
```

Also, if you need to access state in your epics, you might have to use the second parameter state$ whose type is `StatesObservable<T>`. Where T is the interface that defines the structure of your entire redux state.